# Command runs okay but not from bash script

Tags: shell-script, quoting, filenames

Under `~/Pictures` there are some sub-directories containing jpegs like
`~/Pictures/Pics 1/img.jpg`.

From `bash`:

```
~/Pictures $ `file Pics\ 1/img.jpg`
```

Output:

```
Pics 1/img.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard:: [TIFF image data,
little-endian, direntries=12, description=....
```

I create `script.sh` and `chmod a+x`

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=$(builtin printf "%q" "$1")
CMD="file $VAR"
EXIF=eval "$CMD"
echo "$EXIF"
```

```
~/Pictures $ ./script.sh Pics\ 1/img.jpg
```

Output:

```
./script.sh: line 4: file Pics\ 1/img.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Also tried full path for img.jpg and `/usr/bin/file`

OS: Raspbian updated/upgraded
I've read several similar questions/answers and didn't get the key

**EDIT:**    Maybe it would be useful for someone to use `exiftool` instead of `file`
Because of locale issue I posted as a comment in the answer marked as solution (and because I get more info) I am going to use exiftool.
script.sh:

```
 #!/bin/bash
COMM="/usr/bin/exiftool -Description \"$1\""    
DESCR=$(eval "$COMM")    
DESCRIPTION=${DESCR#"Description                     : "}
echo "$DESCRIPTION"
```

It outputs correctly the metatada *Description* with special characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to try to be smart with quoting in the script.  Just make sure that you double quote the expansion of `$1` (and any other variable):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

exif=$( file "$1" )
printf '%s\n' "$exif"
```

or just

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file "$1"
```

To run:

```
./script.sh Pics\ 1/img.jpg
```

or,

```
./script.sh "Pics 1/img.jpg"
```

or,

```
./script.sh "Pics 1"/img.jpg
```

What happens in your script is that you make the `\` part of the pathname.  It's not part of the pathname, it's just there to escape the space on the command line.

Also, you are assigning the string `eval` to the environment variable `EXIF` for the duration of the `file` command.  You probably meant `EXIF=$( eval "$CMD" )`, but this is not needed (see above).

If you *really* wanted to store the full `file` command in a variable, you should be using an array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cmd=( file "$1" )
exif=$( "${cmd[@]}" )
printf '%s\n' "$exif"
```

Again, no need for `eval` here.

... not even if we write it for `/bin/sh` (which does not have arrays, but that does have the list of positional parameters, also available in `bash` obviously):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -- file "$1"
exif=$( "$@" )
printf '%s\n' "$exif"
```

Comment: That simple. I already had started in that way. I don't exactly recall why I did get a 'not found' error msg because of the blank not escaped. I believe that time I mixed `sh` and `bash`, I should have executed `./script.sh` instead of `sh script.sh`. There are times that it would easy to clean all and start over. Thank for the plus, next step, building the array.

Comment: From the `file` output: "description=" I get `\303\251` instead of `é`. I added `LC_ALL=es_UY.UTF-8` to the script but nothing changes

Comment: @dstonek You would have to `export` the `LC_ALL` variable in the script, or it will not be seen by `file`.

Comment: I already did that, I forgot to add `export` in the last comment. Added after `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @dstonek You may want to ask a completely new question about this specific issue. I'm not very good with locale-related issues.

Comment: I added an edit to the question, please!

Comment: @dstonek You should not quote the whole command in the command substitution, only the `$1` bit, as `"$1"`, nothing more (the tilde will not expand in quotes).  You have already accepted my answer, you can't add more to the question now. Ask a completely new question if you have further issues.